# Moving from IO to NIO - Networking, IllegalBlockingModeException

Tags: java, networking, io, nio

I'm attempting to move my networking over from standard IO to NIO and following the few tutorials that there are to attempt to figure it out, while me, myself, and I decided it'd be a great idea to spend my first week rewriting the core for all of the applications logic handling, I never would have imagined that I wouldn't be able to set up the basic networking.

Currently the networking is at a very basic stage, everything is tossed inside of a while-loop and I can't honestly say I've put any attempt into it to make it look nice, considering I haven't a clue what I'm doing my goal was to figure out how to do it first, then go back and give it a makeover.

Here's the code I use to initialize my server:

```
    // Initializes the TCP Server and all of its components.
private void initTcpServer(int port) {
    try {
        // Create a new selector
        Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider()
                .openSelector();

        // Create a new non-blocking server socket channel;
        this.serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        this.serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Bind the server socket to the specified address and port
        this.serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(
                new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", port));

        // Register the server socket channel, indicating an interest in
        // accepting new connections
        this.serverSocketChannel.register(socketSelector,
                SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        // Set the selector for the server instance.
        this.selector = socketSelector;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then this class implements the Runnable interface, and a new thread is started directly after this method completes, in this thread we contain the following code:

```
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            selector.selectNow();
        } catch (IOException io) {
            return;
        }

        Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            SelectionKey key = it.next();

            if (!key.isValid()) {
                it.remove();
                continue;
            }

            try {
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.handleConnection(key);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    Connection connection = (Connection) key.attachment();
                    if (connection != null) {
                        try {
                            connection.getMasterProtocol()
                                    .decode(connection,
                                            connection.getInputStream());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                it.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This, from my understanding is what allows us to handle our connections and data based off of a `SelectionKey`.. and is what all of the NIO based networking runs from, you'll see that I'm calling two different methods to make this not so much of a mess, the first one is `#handleConnection` and the other one is a decode function.

The handle connection method creates a new instance of my `Connection` class and attatches it to the SelectionKey, like so:

```
    public Connection(SelectionKey key) {
    try {
        // For an accept to be pending the channel must be a server socket channel.
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel)key.channel();

        // Accept the connection and make it non-blocking.
        this.socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
        this.socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        // Set up other user data.
        this.inputStream = new DataInputStream(socketChannel.socket().getInputStream());
        this.masterProtocol = new MasterProtocol();

        // Register the new SocketChannel with our Selector, indicating
        // we'd like to be notified when there's data waiting to be read.
        key = this.socketChannel.register(OGServer.getInstance().getSelector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);
        key.attach(this);

        // Add the current <SelectorKey, Connection> to the current connections collection.
        connections.put(key, this);

        Log.debug(getClass(), "Connection constructed successfully.");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error is called when I attempt to call the `MasterProtocol#decode` method, which looks like this:

```
public Object decode(Connection connection, DataInputStream dataInputStream) throws IOException {
    if(connection.getState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
        byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(dataInputStream);
        if(bytes.length < 4) {
            System.out.println("Not enough bytes read.");
            return null;
        }

        int bufferSize = dataInputStream.readInt();

        System.out.println("Buffer Size: " + bufferSize);

        while(bytes.length < bufferSize) {
            return null;
        }

        int test = dataInputStream.readInt();

        System.out.println("Test: " + test);

        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The error seems to be called when the `DataInputStream` tries to read from the network, more specifically on this line of code:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(dataInputStream);
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:190)
at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:100)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:70)
at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:115)
at net.ogserver.framework.net.protocol.MasterProtocol.decode(MasterProtocol.java:29)
at net.ogserver.framework.net.OGServer.run(OGServer.java:146)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The 'IllegalBlockingModeException' exception is what's throwing me off, as all of the information I've found was for setting up a Non-blocking server, but the DataInputStream  implementation was my own, so I must have done something wrong somewhere. NIO is a completely different world from IO, but learning is learning, eh?

EDIT: I guess it'd help to know how I'm sending the data from the client, it's just a very basic test application that does this:

```
        socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5055);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBoolean(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving to NIO in non-blocking you can't keep using streams. If you want to use streams there is no advantage to using NIO at all. I would just stop the migration project now.

Comment: The project was originally written in Netty, then moved to IO, and now I'm trying to write it using NIO, Netty is based off a NIO and I'm just having some problems figuring it all out. I'm doing this as a learning project, and considering the original application was written using netty which was built upon NIO, wouldn't it make sense to be able to do it in NIO to begin with?  I've just moved a bare-bones version of Netty's channel buffer and the input/out streams for the buffer to my project, but I'm still having a hard time figuring out exactly how to use them, more studying is required.

Comment: Note, that none of the functionality has changed between the migration from Netty->IO, with the Netty version I made use of the ServerBootstrap(NioServerSocketChannelFactory) and the Pipeline() feature, using an upstream and a downstream header.

Comment: I can only repeat. You have to either get rid of NIO, get rid of non-blocking mode, or get rid of the streams.